# Spring Batch partitioning a step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have multiple CSV files to read. I want the processing to be done one file at a time. Rather than reading all the records till it reaches commit level.

I have put together a job which uses partition but on running the job I see that there are two entries for every row. As if the job is running twice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/database.xml" />



     <bean id="asyncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" >
     <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="1"></property>
     </bean>  

     <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner" scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters[filePath]}/*.dat" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multiResourceReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters[filePath]}/*.dat"></property>
        <property name="delegate" ref="logItFileReader"></property>
    </bean>



    <batch:job id="remediationJob">
        <batch:step id="partitionedStep" >
            <batch:partition step="readWriteContactsPartitionedStep" partitioner="partitioner">
                <batch:handler task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" />
            </batch:partition>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <batch:step id="readWriteContactsPartitionedStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="READ_UNCOMMITTED"/>
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="rawItemDatabaseWriter" commit-interval="10" skip-policy="pdwUploadSkipPolicy"/>
        <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="customItemReaderListener"></batch:listener>
                    <batch:listener ref="csvLineSkipListener"></batch:listener>
                    <batch:listener ref="getCurrentResourceChunkListener"></batch:listener>

                </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>    
    </batch:step>


    <bean id="logItFileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <!-- Read a csv file -->

        <property name="strict" value="false"></property>
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <!-- split it -->
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="@##@" />
                        <property name="strict" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <!-- map to an object -->
                    <bean class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.vo.CSVDataVOFieldMapper">

                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rawItemDatabaseWriter" class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.csv.RawItemDatabaseWriter"
        scope="step">
    </bean>

    <bean id="pdwUploadSkipPolicy"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy" />

    <bean id="csvDataVO" class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.vo.CSVDataVO"
        scope="prototype"></bean>


    <!-- BATCH LISTENERS -->

    <bean id="pdwFileMoverListener"
        class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.listener.PdwFileMoverListener"
        scope="step">
    </bean>

    <bean id="csvLineSkipListener"
        class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.listener.CSVLineSkipListener"
        scope="step">
    </bean>

    <bean id="customItemReaderListener"
        class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.listener.CustomItemReaderListener"></bean>

     <bean id="getCurrentResourceChunkListener" 
          class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.listener.GetCurrentResourceChunkListener">
        <property name="proxy" ref ="multiResourceReader" />
    </bean>
    <!-- 
    <bean id="stepListener" class="org.kp.oppr.remediation.batch.listener.ExampleStepExecutionListener">
        <property name="resources" ref="multiResourceReader"/>
    </bean>
     -->
    <!-- Skip Policies -->

</beans>
```

Is there something I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Well You have 2 questions there

1 - "I want the processing to be done one file at a time. Rather than reading all the records till it reaches commit level."
 Set Commit-Interval to 1 - It will read an item, process it and the writer will wait until it has 1 item to write.

2 - As if the job is running twice.

Looks like it will run as many times as the number of files you have.

You should not use a MultiResourceItemReader for this step. 
 The partitioner splits the resources into multiple and create separate execution contexts. 
Your MultiResourceItemReader is again considering all the files because of the resources property being set.

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to reply to my question. However, my requirement is to process one file completely before moving to the next one because I need to collect few statistic for each file read.

Comment: Yes, it will work. 
Commit Interval of 1 will ensure that an item has gone through the reader and writer before the next item in its **context** is picked.

But, since your job is partitioned. The processing is done in parallel.